# How to use docker container as host with ansible running in a docker container on gitlab-ci?

Tags: docker, ansible, gitlab-ci

I would like to test our ansible deployment with gitlab-ci using docker containers.
I'm trying to create a job which uses a docker conainter installed ansible in it and use another docker container as host for an ansible-playbook.

```
deploy-test:
    stage: deploy-test
    image: stretch-ansible-docker-container
    script:
        - ansible-playbook -i <use-another-docker-container> test-deploy.yaml
```

How can I create and define the docker-container which should be used as host?

Comment: IME Ansible playbooks want to do a lot of things (control user accounts, start multiple services, change config files, ...) and you’d be better off testing against a full VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different approaches, mainly they depend on whether you want to use `docker-in-docker` for building dockers or just share host's `/var/run/docker.sock`. If second option, your steps would like somehow like:

First create Dockerfiles for your lovely containers. Possibly put them inside your project's sources, lets say `Dockerfiles\` subfolder

Then prepend one stage into your pipeline, e.g.:
**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - prepare-dockers
  - test

prepare:
  stage: prepare-dockers
  image: docker:latest
  script:
    - docker build -t <use-another-docker-container> Dockerfiles
```

Thus you get your container ready on next stages. Dont forget, if you are using docker sharing (not pure `dind`), you're connected to your host's docker registry and all images will appear there.

But you should also not forget to share docker socket by editing `gitlab-config.toml` to allow docker sharing (expose `/var/run/docker.sock`).

Comment: It is very good idea, but we have a common repository with the prebuilt images and I'd use these. I have no clue how can I create containers from these and reference them as hosts for ansible-playbook running in a docker container.

Comment: This concept has no conflicts with external repositories concept. Just push the built image into any repository to wish

Comment: Btw, gitlab now provides built in docker registry for convenience